# Cloudflare 521 error on WordPress edit screen

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare

I have a small WordPress (v5.7.2) site running on an AWS Lightsail instance. Cloudflare is managing the DNS. Everything seemed to be running smoothly until today when I went to edit a post. The dashboard was working normally, but when I click to edit a post, I landed on a white screen of death. I viewed the source and saw that it is Cloudflare's 521 error page. All other pages seem to work fine. If I turn on "Developer Mode" in Cloudflare, the problem goes away, but when I turn it back on it returns. I don't have any caching plugins installed.

I tried Purging the cache in cloudflare and it didn't fix it. I tried changing the SSL setting to flexible (instead of full) and it didn't fix it. I logged into the AWS instance and clicked around the Plesk panel and didn't notice any issues. I tried rebooting the instance and it didn't fix it. Although, now when I view the source it seems to be the login screen.

Any ideas why this is happening?

There's some errors in the console that may or may not be relevant:
[image]

Comment: If developer mode fixes it, then you need to look at all your cloudflare settings to determine which one is breaking the admin. I would try disabling rocket loader first, if you have that enabled, as it is the most likely culprit. Also, do you have Cloudflare APO for Wordpress enabled? Do you have any cloudflare page rules defined? You're going to have to go through disabling things one by one until you find the reason, or maybe add a page rule for `wp-admin/*` to disable some of the cloudflare features.

Answer (score 1):

Confusingly / frustratingly... this issue resolved its self without any further troubleshooting by me. This makes me think it must have been some kind of Cloudflare hiccup.